# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined - bootstrap 4 install

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, sass, gulp

I'm using below url to start bootstrap 4 with gulp:
https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial

But I got below Error when i run gulp command.

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:39:5
at req_ (X:\Users\pradeep.patel\Desktop\PP\Website\PP\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
at Object.req [as require] (X:\Users\pradeep.patel\Desktop\PP\Website\PP\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
at Object. (X:\Users\pradeep.patel\Desktop\PP\Website\PP\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1074:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)

Answer (score 0):

I have run below commands, and issue resolved:

npm install -g minimatch (Enter)

npm install -g graceful-fs (Enter)

npm link gulp (Enter)

Thanks,
PP